# Overloading new and delete vs Custom Allocator

Tags: c++, overloading, new-operator, delete-operator, allocator

How should I approach custom memory allocation for my class. I have seen both methods used extensively. Using a custom allocator, like all stl containers are doing, which make it part of their type with a template type parameter. Or overload the `new` and `delete` functions and possibly placement `new` and placement `delete` as well. I have visited and read many questions and answers on both of these techniques, but I can't figure out which one should be used in a particular case. Clearly all the stl containers were designed with a custom allocator in mind. Why not overload `new` and `delete` (etc.) instead though, in order to satisfy your memory requirements? It seems to me that overloading `new` and `delete` can accomplish everything an allocator could and in fact possibly easier with less hassle. This may be especially true in C++17 which comes with a plethora of possible overloads which can even specify alignment requirements, nothrow tag versions etc.

We are told that in C++ we should generally use `new` and `delete` for a typical heap allocation (or more frequently smart pointers, but this isn't a "smart" discussion now, this is low level). But what if we use an allocator to allocate our object instead with `.allocate()` and then construct with `.construct()` (I believe the last function is deprecated now though). We would essentially be doing the same thing that `new std::string{"Hello"}` is doing.

Only thing the C++ Core Guidelines mentions about this matter is [this](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-pair) (ie. nothing). I can't find much else really. And what about thread safety and security? I have surmised that (custom) memory management is probably the most important aspect of advanced c++ so I must understand exactly what I'm doing.

My question is which one of the two methods to choose to manage the memory of my own class, implementing a custom memory allocator (like the `stl` containers), or overloading `new`, `delete`, `new[]`, `delete[]`, placement `new` ... and why? Some other good practices and guidelines of where and when would also be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your class?

Comment: @Nelfeal I'm broadly speaking. When to use one method versus the other.

Comment: Well, broadly speaking, it depends on what your class is / does / is used for. I personally wouldn't overload `new` and the like, except maybe for debugging purposes. But then, I'm also not fond of allocators. There are other ways for a class to manage memory, and in the end, it really does depends on the role of that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Broadly speaking, an `Allocator` type is used when an object of one type (typically a container) needs to manage memory to hold an object or objects **of some other type**. Overloading `operator new` and `operator delete` within a class is used when objects **of that type** need some special memory management.